# Java - Prevent JPanel from repainting on initialize

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(new Color(111, 0, 255));
        g.fillOval(300, 300, 200, 200);

        g.dispose();
    };
};
```

Why does this immediately draw, and also draw every time I resize it's JFrame?
Is there anyway to only make it draw when I call `panel.repaint();`?

Comment: Swing components are smart. They automatically repaint themselves when required. Why do you care? Also, don't invoke `g.dispose()`. You only use that method when you use the Graphics.create() method to create your own temporary Grapics object.

Comment: @camickr Well, my original code doesn't have to draw very fast at all only like 1 time a five seconds, and also, it can only draw if a variable that is initialized after the panel is defined, so that's why I am asking.

Comment: All components should have a default state for painting. If you later change the variable (property of your component) then you should automatically repaint the component. This is the way all Swing components work. That is all the "setter" methods will cause a repaint.

Comment: @camickr So how can I prevent that?

Comment: @Murplyx I suggest looking into the XY problem. I don't think "*preventing painting on initialization*" is the actual problem, rather than your solution for what you want to achieve. Tell us, what are you trying to achieve? That way, we can help get you on the right path

Comment: I want to do exactly what I asked for.

Comment: @Murplyx, prevent what? I've already suggested you should not try to control Swing. Automatic repainting of Swing components is a good feature. For example, a JTextField is designed to paint text. But if you don't add text, nothing is painted. Your component should be the same. The painting is done based on the properties of the components. If the properties are not set then I guess you don't paint. Your question does not have enough information to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Still think you are going about this incorrectly.

The only possible solution I can think of is to try using:

```
JComponent.setIgnoreRepaint( true );
```

Comment: Can you add some more code like where am I going to put that line? ty

Answer (score 0):

try to use some flag to determine if condition meet

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(!ConditionMeet) return;

        //some code to executed when condition meet
    };
```